# By code, how can I send a hard disk drive to sleep

Tags: c#, windows, hardware

I have lots of hard disk drives in my computer (7).

When they are not used the power option send them to sleep after a while.
But because everything makes a lot of noise I would like to send them to sleep when I want, not just after the default system timeout.

On Windows (XP and up), preferably in C#,

**How can I send a disk to sleep by code?**

Thanks a lot in advance for your help...

Comment: You could just get some SSDs. :)

Comment: WD Caviar Green is a good and much more affordable alternative to SSD.  Very cool & quiet.

Comment: I'm sure there's a way to do it, it just might take ages to get an answer from someone who knows it well enough.

Comment: like Mark suggested the trick probably lies in the fact that we can only set the downtime for a disk. That means that maybe we could change the power management policy (any samples someone?) and use a small value. This will shut down all the disks not used...

any idea if this can be controled individually?

Answer (score 1):

I do not know of the API to do this directly but there are tools that can do it.  One that I have seen is [Hard Disk Sleeper](http://www.softlookup.com/display.asp?id=9315).  I have not used it on my own machines so I cannot speak to its quality or effectiveness.

Comment: the tool dates from the 99's and it looks like it's a shareware (read, cannot be used any more) but thanks I prefer code...

Comment: Also looks limited to IDE/EIDE drives.

Comment: Maybe I have a hint here :
http://smartmontools.sourceforge.net/
http://hdparm-win32.dyndns.org/hdparm/

unfortunately, I'm stuck as it seems that my disks can't use that stuff as they are RAID and it needs smart/ata/sata disks or specific RAID treatment.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to do this if you send ATA commands directly to a drive using [IOCTL_ATA_PASS_THROUGH](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms804551.aspx).  You will need to pass the SLEEP command.

I don't think that this is a project for C# though.

Comment: any sample of how to use this? in any language ;) the msdn page does not help much... shall this be used in drivers or can it be use in user mode programs?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, this is an ATA command that sets the *spin down time8 - meaning it's the drive itself that shuts down. You could use IOCTL_ATA_PASS_THROUGH to send commands directly to the drive - but I'm afraid you'd do no better than just setting it to some min value (which I don't know what it is, but it should be in the ATA specs).

Edit: Looks like the venerable [hdparm supports it](http://linux.die.net/man/8/hdparm), so it must be in the ATA spec:

> -y 
>   Force an IDE drive to immediately enter the low power consumption standby mode, usually causing it to spin down.
>
> -Y Force an IDE drive to immediately enter the lowest power consumption sleep mode, causing it to shut down completely. A hard or soft reset is required before the drive can be accessed again (the Linux IDE driver will automatically handle issuing a reset if/when needed).

Since [hdparm](http://sourceforge.net/projects/hdparm/) (and the underlying Linux kernel it uses to communicate with the drive) is GPL - you should be able to crib the specifics from there if you don't have an ATA spec handy.

Or, just use the [win32 port](http://hdparm-win32.dyndns.org/hdparm/).

Comment: That also means it will only work with ata/sata disks and the like?

Thanks for the notice that the disk shuts down by itself and that you can only set the down time...

Comment: Yes - it's only for ATA drives. If you have SCSI, I think you'd need to send a SCSI Stop Unit command. Linux has scsi-tools and scsi-idle for this.

Answer (score 1):

On windows you can simply use "GetDevicePowerState"  function returning FALSE if the drive is sleeping (not rotating).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-getdevicepowerstate

Answer (score 0):

I honestly don't think it is possible to do that by using only C# (i.e. the .NET framework).

Regardless, I would start by learning about [WMI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc302051.aspx) and [ACPI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Configuration_and_Power_Interface).

This tends to be the sort of thing that requires you to delve into a lower level language (at least to figure out the API calls to use with P\Invoke) because it usually involves interacting closely with the Operating System or possibly directly with a driver.

Maybe you could start by investigating the [Windows Power Management Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa373163(VS.85).aspx) although I don't think it allows control of the individual hard drives.

Comment: While there may not be a native C# way to do this, there is a high likelihood it can still be controlled from C# via PInvoke or COM interop.

Comment: Yes, I made a correction. What I wanted to say is that it is likely you'll have to look for a solution in native C++ and then port the implementation to C# using P\Invoke.

Comment: last time I checked setpowerstate with wmi it said it's not implemented.

also, you are right, it seems I cannot control individual drives with the power mangement functions. or at least I don't know how to do it.

Last, I'm taking a solution in any language if I don't have the choice...