# C++ hibernate a hard disk (programmatically)

Tags: c++, windows-7, hard-drive

In OS's like WS2008R2 and its compliment 7, I need to hibernate one (of two) hard drives. The hard drive in question gets hot (cos its old) and is only used to write images of the main HD too once a week.

I would like to issue it a "sleep" or "hibernate" command.

Also, I dont want it to wake up when unless an app is needs to read/write to it, meaning is the partition file table cached in these OS's?

Added:

The other thread did not answer the question.

I do not want a tool, I need to write code

Notwithstanding the [arguments](http://www.annoyances.org/exec/forum/winxp/t1263483982) against doing this

WMI might be the way to go does anyone know?

From what i understand [IOCTL_ATA_PASS_THROUGH](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff559309.aspx) will not do it.

Ideally I would like to access the [power management controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa373163%28VS.85%29.aspx) directly but it is unclear if this can be done programmatically without using a [Windows Group Policy](http://www.gpoguy.com/)

Ill take code in any language at this point....

Comment: it's maybe useful to know wheter you want run the code as a) normal user b) as administrator or c) from kernel mode

Comment: There are existing tools which will let one issue commands to a HDD/controller; might not be practical to reinvent this. You also have to take the *host* environment into account (said tools normally do this to different extents).

Comment: possible duplicate of [By code, how can I send a hard disk drive to sleep](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/860986/by-code-how-can-i-send-a-hard-disk-drive-to-sleep)

Comment: ComplEment, not complIment, not unless WS2008R2 was saying something nice about Windows 7.